# Correct wiring of a variable resistor

Tags: resistors, soldering, potentiometer

I built the following schematic and I made a mistake. I wired the 4.7M preset reversed. 
This is the original schematic:

[image]

And this is the schematic that I drew in Kicad:

[image]

I already built the PCB but I am wondering what can happen if I wired the 4.7M multi turn preset reversed ? Will the soldering station work correctly ?
I know that the direction of increasing the resistance changes, but I am wondering what other things can occur ?

Comment: Think about it. One of the 2 ends of the pot is redundant here, so it becomes a 2 terminal part. It works. I future remember if the part pins are numbered pin 2 wiper CW goes from 1 to 3

Comment: @mike: I've "inlined" the schematics for you. (You should have been able to manage this.) You should turn of the grid before taking screengrabs. It helps text legibility.

Comment: It's helpful to think about how the finished assembly works - you want clockwise motion of the trim tool to increase the gain (or offset) of the amplifier.  It's much easier to set the circuit up if it follows the usual common conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "preset", a digital potentiometer? 
If it's linear, then reversing the direction is the only thing you'll see. If it's logarithmic, adjustment may become very non-linear i.e. you'll see almost all of the change in right in the beginning or end.

Comment: I do not know for sure if it is linear or logarithmic ? It looks like the one here, and it has the same PN: https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/296-776415.pdf But it is from China.

Comment: @mike_mike  So it's a trimmer i.e. a small potentiometer not meant to be adjusted by hand. It's impossible to say without an actual datasheet if it's linear, try turning the screw to the halfway position and measure the resistance. If it's about 2.35M, you've got a linear trimmer.  If it's more like 470k or 4.2M, you've got a logarithmic trimmer.

Comment: As far as I'm aware *preset* or *preset pot* is common usage for *a small potentiometer not meant to be adjusted by hand*. They are usually used for *preset*ting an adjustable parameter of a circuit...

Comment: So the circuit will work fine if this trimmer is connected reversed ? @Barleyman (please have a look at the schematics from the original message). I checked the trimmer and it is linear.

Comment: I checked the trimmer and it is linear. It will work ? @Barleyman

Comment: @mike_mike Makes absolutely no difference in that case then.

Comment: @nekomatic never heard of that term. A trimmer is a trimmer is a trimmer. Not to say it may not be used in some circles but generally professional designs do not have trimmers to start with. It's too much work to hand - tune something for mass production! If you want variable gain it's usually done with a DAC or a dip switch or an analogue switch. I guess precision instrumentation which costs a lot to calibrate would be an exception.